# Apache Flink - Task Manager HA setup

Tags: apache-flink

In mission critical setups, constant availability is a must.

We are thinking on embracing Apache Flink as our Streaming engine but we have challenging SLAs.

Our job plan will be based on a single window thus replicating the job could be an answer.

What is the advised setup for high availability in Flink to guarantee that service is always up? Job Manager HA is not sufficient as it does not guarantee the neededul.

Comment: Why does Flink's normal HA capabilities are not sufficient for your use case? Is the job restart time too high because of large state?

Comment: They are not sufficient. We have very thight SLAs, thus any downtime is critical for us. In other components we need to recurr to replication or even blue-green if we are talking about deployments. We are thinking on having 2 jobs per metric in active-passive mode and we will implement the failover strategy. Thoughts on this?

Comment: How should the active passive mode be decided (ZooKeeper)? If you have a deterministic data flow with idempotent writes to an external store, it should be fairly easy. Otherwise you would need to have a deduplication mechanism if you have exactly once processing requirements.